# Java thread pool, how to stop a long running thread immediately using shutdownNow()?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, legacy-code

I have a main thread that creates several threads using Executors

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
```

Each thread has long running jobs (some legacy code from another team) which might run for hours.

Now I want to shutdown from the main thread using

```
executor.shutdownNow()
```

And I want the threads to be able to stop immediately, how could I do that?

In the thread, say we have such code:

```
public void run() {
doA();
doB();
doC();
...
...
```

}

Now my issue is, even if I called `shutdownNow`, the running thread will run to the end then stop. I'd like to know how to stop and exit.

Comment: Just wondering why you are using a thread for sequential tasks ? May be redesign a bit and use Callables instead of Runnables in your threads you could try and call someTask.cancel() to get rid of the running tasks at the time of shutdownNow() call.

Comment: it's a design issue. I'll ask for timewindow to do this later. For this question, I just want to confirm there is no good way in Java to stop running thread like a short circuit.

Comment: @Ran Does my answer satisfy your constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a slightly tricky situation indeed!

Can we make use of a hook that the JDK has provided in the form of `ThreadFactory` that is consulted when the associated thread pool is creating a thread in which your legacy task will run? If yes, then why not make your legacy code run in a `daemon` thread? We know that the JVM exits when the last `non-daemon` thread exits. So, if we make each thread that the thread pool uses to run your legacy tasks a daemon thread, there is a chance that we can make the `shutdownNow()` call more responsive:

```
public class LegacyCodeExecutorEx {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2, new DaemonThreadFactory());

        executor.submit(new LegacySimulator());
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        executor.shutdownNow();
    }

    static class LegacySimulator implements Runnable {
        private final AtomicLong theLong;
        LegacySimulator() {
            theLong = new AtomicLong(1);
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (long i = 10; i < Long.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
                theLong.set(i*i);
            }
            System.out.println("Done!");
        }
    }
    static class DaemonThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {
        @Override
        public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
            Thread t = new Thread(r);
            t.setName("Daemon Thread");
            t.setDaemon(true);
            return t;
        }
    }
}
```

If you play with `setDaemon(true)` line, you will see that this code either responds to the exit of the main thread (which is `non-daemon`) either immediately or takes its own sweet time to finish the task.

Is making your legacy-code-running threads `daemon` threads a possibility? If yes, you could give this a try.

Comment: Yes, the daemon resolved most of the issues for now. I had to keep their legacy codes as-is first. It's time to break down now. You won't believe how many duplicated codes they had there........but thanks a lot for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a flag in the `Runnable` object instantiation that checks between tasks whether you need to stop or not.

```
public void run() {
    if(timeToShutdown) return;
    doA();
    if(timeToShutdown) return;
    doB();
    /*etc*/
}
```

Threads in Java operate at a (relatively) low level. Short of directly shutting down the entire JVM, the only way to manually force the stop of a Thread is using Deprecated behavior from Java 1.0/1.1, which pretty much noone wants you to use.

Comment: Thanks for replying. That's the last way I want to do, I also had similar approach like you mentioned but I used if (Thread.interrupted())...the thing is every doA(), doB() calls also a lot of things, in each of them it could be a long running (I/O mostly), if I cannot stop them correctly, our PM guys will rerun the job then I could have some duplicated threads working on the same thing, that's really a bad design in the beginning....

Comment: @Ran If you need the tasks themselves to conclude at a moment's notice, then you need to add similar logic to those as well. If that's not possible, then you are indeed dealing with a rather severe design issue in your code.

Comment: sigh....yes...it's a legacy codes from so many people to me. They managed a thread, processing millions of lines of text files in this thread. There will be sanitycheck, de-duplication, unique id, calculation...etc, a lot of things put into one function. I dislike this but it's too big move to refactor them. Now they got big issues that when something is wrong and they used to rerun, and rerun gave more issues. The root cause is this shutdown didn't really shutdown running threads, so new thread will work with old ones on same file, messed up everything...................